# Как сохранить историю команд в файл в psql? При вводе "\s filename" выводит "в данной среде история не поддерживается"

Tags: postgresql, psql

Пытался вывести\сохранить в файл историю выполненных команд в psql. Вводил команды "\s" и "\s filename", но натыкался на сообщение "в данной среде история не поддерживается".

Как решить данную проблему?

[image: Ввод команд в SQL Shell (psql)]